What have I missed here in this Euclidean algorithm trying to find D of RSA

Given the RSA public key find the decryption key d and decrypt the ciphertext c=8.
Known information:

n=119, p=17, q=7, e=13
$\phi(n) = (p-1)(q-1) = 16\times 6=96$

Equation for finding d:
$$ed\equiv1 \mod \phi(n)$$

Attempt:
$ed\equiv 1 \mod \phi(n)$
$13d\equiv 1 \mod 96$
$96 = 7 \times 13 + 5$
$13 = 2 \times 5 + 3$
$5 = 2 \times 2 + 1$
Reverse:
$1 = 5 - 2 \times 2$
$1 = 5 - 2(13 - 2 \times 5)$
$1 = 5 - 2(13 - 2(5))$
$1 = 5 - 2(13 - 2(96 - 7 \times 13))$
$1 = 5 - 2(13 - 2(96) + 14(13))$
$1 = 5 - 2(13) + 4(96) - 28(13)$
$1 = 5 + 4(96) - 30(13)$

And now I am stuck here. Not sure, what the final step has to be. The correct answer is d=37.
New Attempt:
$13d\equiv 1 \mod 96$
$96 = 7 \times 13 + 5$
$13 = 2 \times 5 + 3$
$5 = 1 \times 3 + 2$
$3 = 1 \times 2 + 1$
Reverse:
$1 = 3 - 1 \times 2$
$1 = 3 - 1 \times (5 - 1 \times 3)$
$1 = 3 - 1 \times (5 - 1 \times (13 - 2 \times 5)$
$1 = 3 - 1 \times (5 - 1 \times (13 - 2 \times (96 - 7 \times 13)))$
$1 = 3 - 1 \times (5 - 1 \times (13 - 2(96) + 14(13))$
$1 = 3 - 1 \times (5 - 1(13) + 2(96) - 14(13))$
$1 = 3 - 5 + 13 - 2(96) + 14(13)$
$1 = 3 - 5 + 15(13) - 2(96)$
$3 - 5 + 15(13) - 2(96) = 1$

You made a mistake, $2\not= 13 - 2 \times 5$.

So, $4 \times 3=12 + 1$ instead?

@Kolja unfortunately, I do not know those tricks! Can you tell me, $13 = 4 \times 3 +1$ correct?

First of all, early on when you're still finding the GCD, $5 = 2 \cdot 2 + 1$ is not the correct next step. After you've written $13$ as $2 \cdot 5 + 3$, you are taking the GCD of $5$ and $3$. We'd write $5 = 1 \cdot 3 + 2$, and then write $3 = 1 \cdot 2 + 1$. However, rather than doing the final few steps, it might be easier to eyeball $5$ and $3$ and say $$2 \cdot \underline 3 - 1 \cdot \underline 5 = 1.$$ Your second mistake is that at some point, while working backwards, you have to replace the $5$. I have underlined the numbers whose GCD we're taking so that it's easier to keep track; we should always replace the smaller of the two underlined numbers. So we'll get:

$2 \cdot (\underline{13} - 2 \cdot \underline{5}) - 1 \cdot \underline{5} = 1$, or $2 \cdot \underline{13} - 5 \cdot \underline{5} = 1$.
$2 \cdot \underline{13} - 5 \cdot (\underline{96} - 7 \cdot \underline{13}) = 1$, or $37 \cdot \underline{13} - 5 \cdot \underline{96} = 1$.

Your third mistake, as pointed out in the comments, was an arithmetic error. You avoid this in reality by using a computer to perform extended GCD rather than doing it by hand. However, if you are doing work by hand, you avoid making arithmetic errors by checking your work, and the extended GCD algorithm offers a great way to do this: whenever we get an expression like $2 \cdot 13 - 5 \cdot 5= 1$, we check whether $2 \cdot 13 - 5 \cdot 5$ is in fact $1$.
(For example, in an earlier draft of this post, I wrote $36 \cdot \underline{13} - 5 \cdot \underline{96} = 1$ instead of $37$. Then I looked at that and said, "That can't be right... the left-hand side is divisible by $3$, so it can't be equal to $1$." So I checked my work and realized that I had incorrectly computed $2 + 5 \cdot 7$.)

Making the changes you proposed, I am left with: $3 - 5 + 15(13) -2(96) = 1$ seems very strange!

You have not made the changes I proposed. You are still making the second mistake, where you keep replacing one of the two terms while leaving the other one alone, except now it's the 3 you're leaving alone. After you write $1 = 3 - 1 \times (5 - 1 \times 3)$, first collect the 3's and 5's to get $1 = 2 \times 3 - 1 \times 5$. Then, replace the 3 by $13 - 2 \times 5$...

Hi I am a bit confused by, First collect the 3's and 5's from $1 = 3 - 1 \times (5 - 1 \times 3)$ do you, simply mean that $1 = 3 - 1(5) +1(3)$ meaning that, next I group the terms who are alike, $1 = 2(3) -1(5)$ and then finally replace the 5, I think I got what you mean.

Yes: you group the terms that are alike, so $1 = 2(3) - 1(5)$ is what you do next. But the next thing you do is replace the $3$, not the $5$. You always choose the smaller of the two options to replace. In the step after that, when you have $1 = 2(13) - 5(5)$, the $5$ is the smaller option, so then you replace the $5$.

I got now: $1 = 37(13) - 5(96)$ does this seem correct?

Yes! You can also already see it in the answer :)
